# OCR software to convert pdf to doc in Farsi

Tags: ocr, web

Most of OCRs in Farsi are framework-dependent and not free. Is there any OCR in Farsi that is under web and free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tooska Farsi OCR](http://tooska.co) is a web-based OCR, which uses modern learning techniques to boost accuracy on the Farsi language  (Disclaimer: I'm on Tooska's development team).

Farsi is a cursive language which adds much complexity for its recognition, therefore there are few OCR software that have appropriate accuracy. Moreover most OCR systems are desktop based.

Comment: Is it a free online one?